# Google parental control Family link app doesn't ask for approval

Tags: google-play, parental-control

I've setup google parental control on my children phone, they ask for approval to install a game and i approved it, later i changed my mind and uninstall it from there phone, but they went to play store a re-install it, but this time family link didn't ask for my approval, it's just installed it and showed me a notification that it's been installed. What i want is that whenever they install anything, no matter it was once approved or millions times, google play must ask them for my approval each time it's reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Family Link app lacks the 'whitelist' feature to allow only a strict set of application to install. Unfortunately, the answer is you cannot prevent the installation of a previously installed application (as a previous answer suggested, you could block said apps).

I experimented and unfortunately disabling and re-enabling Family supervision will still allow previously installed apps to install.  Also, the previously installed apps will be available if you get a new device for the child's account.  Or at least, this is the functionality circa Fall 2022.

An extreme solution would be to create a new account, but obviously this is a frustrating answer if you are trying to do something like protect an older family member who has established accounts for billing.

Answer (score 0):

This solution outlined below will not work, but I did read it as a proposed solution elsewhere online.  I thought I would include it and mention it with this warning.

1. Open the **Play Store** app
2. Select the account icon in the upper right corner
3. Choose the **Manage app & device** from the popup menu
4. Select **Manage**
5. Click **Installed**
6. Select **Not Installed**
7. Select all applications you wish to remove in checkable list
8. Click the **Trash Can** icon in the upper right corner

This would disassociate the application from the account in an ideal world; however, it does not and the child account can still reinstall the offending applications.  The parent is notified of this installation, but they cannot prevent it.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you approved the app as `Always allowed app`. To edit app activity:

- Open the Family Link app Family Link and then Select your child.
- On the "App activity" card, tap Set limits or More.
- Next to your desired app, tap Always always allow.

From here you can select an option to:

1. Always allow always allow.
2. Set a time limit Set limit.
3. Set unlimited time Empty hourglass.
4. Block an app Block.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue but rather than doing the "google play delete not installed apps list"-thing which doesnt solve the problem anyway, use this list to search and install the apps you dont want your child to have installed. After that you can manually block these unwanted apps from normal family link app and deinstall them after you've done that. (You can also leave them on the phone, i mean they are blocked anyways, but it should still take memory space so no reason to not deinstall them after)

Now you will see the following if your child tries to reinstall the app from the play store:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G2uj.jpg)

it says "your parents blocked this app" (just in german :) )

This "feature" (if you even want to call it that way) is really stupid and this way might be the only one to solve this problem even if a bit time-intensive. Hope Google will work on Family Link. Big potential but soooo many problems.

Comment: While this will work on the app he mentioned, he might be looking for a more general solution (shortlisting all potentially bad apps is quite the task).